# two types (words?) inside a template in C++

Tags: c++, llvm

In the llvm code, I found this code sample :

```
template <typename TagT, typename... MemberTs> class PointerSumType {
   uintptr_t Value;

   typedef detail::PointerSumTypeHelper<TagT, MemberTs...> HelperT;

 public:
   PointerSumType() : Value(0) {}

   /// A typed constructor for a specific tagged member of the sum type.
   template <TagT N>
   static PointerSumType
   create(typename HelperT::template Lookup<N>::PointerT Pointer) {
     PointerSumType Result;
     void *V = HelperT::template Lookup<N>::TraitsT::getAsVoidPointer(Pointer);
     assert((reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(V) & HelperT::TagMask) == 0 &&
            "Pointer is insufficiently aligned to store the discriminant!");
     Result.Value = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(V) | N;
     return Result;
   }

   TagT getTag() const { return static_cast<TagT>(Value & HelperT::TagMask); }

   template <TagT N> bool is() const { return N == getTag(); }
  //.....
};
```

My question is : what means `template <TagT N>`, how is it possible to have two words inside a template?

Thanks if you take time to answer me.

P.S. you can find this code at http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/PointerSumType_8h_source.html

Comment: `template <typename TagT>` is also two words. How is it possible to not have two words?

Comment: It's __Non-type template parameter__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to comments, I understood! I was dumb : was like but this time the type was TagT and not int. It was confusing because the type of the template was itself a template type... But ok!